# how can i connect my java app to a local file .sql without install any server

Tags: java, sql, database, file, netbeans

is it possible to read data from a local file without install a server
i use netbeans

Comment: and if you open .sql-file with any text-editor what can you see inside ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply read and write a file you can use the java.io or java.nio packages; if you want to access an .sql file as a database: you can't. It's not a database. You'll need to install a database on your pc to do such things.

SQL files are in plain text format and can comprise of several language elements. Multiple statements can be added to a single SQL file if their execution is possible without depending on each other. These SQL commands can be executed by query editors for carrying out CRUD operations. They do not contain any tables for accessing data.

Getting started with a database is fairly simple (if you follow instructions) and Netbeans has a built-in database, but I've never used it.

You can read about mysql here for example:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/index.htm

And on how to connect to databases here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/index.htm